# From .class scope, get CSS custom property (variable) value using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, web-frontend, css-variables

I know you can get the `:root` or `html` custom properties using `window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--foo')`, but I was wondering how you would get the value from a class scoped property?

For example:

```
body {
  --background: white;
}
.sidebar {
  --background: gray;
}
.module {
  background: var(--background);
}
```

How would I get `getPropertyValue('--background')` from `.sidebar`, which would return me `gray` instead of `white`? Am I going the wrong direction by wanting to do this (I have a library that needs the colors passed to it through JS, and they are already defined as custom properties)?

Research:

1. I could probably query for an element with `.sidebar` and get it that way, but it does not seem reliable in case no such element exists.
2. Seems like I can list all properties (https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-all-custom-properties-on-a-page-in-javascript/), but this process seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like your "Research 1.", just check if the element exists to avoid errors.
Notice that if a variable is not defined, it will inherit from the parent.

```js
function getCssVar(selector, style) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector)
  
  // Exit if element doesn't exist
  if(!element) return false
  
  // Exit if variable is not defined
  if(!getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(style)) return false
  
  console.log(`${selector} : ${getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(style)}`) 
}

getCssVar('.exist-and-has-variable', '--background')
getCssVar('.exist-and-no-variable', '--background')

getCssVar('.child-with-variable', '--background')
getCssVar('.child-without-variable', '--background')

getCssVar('.dont-exist', '--background')
```

```css
:root {
  --background: white;
}
.exist-and-has-variable {
  --background: gray;
}
.child-with-variable {
  --background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="exist-and-has-variable">
  <div class="child-with-variable"></div>
  <div class="child-without-variable"></div>
</div>

<div class="exist-and-no-variable">
</div>
```

Comment: So no way to do if the element doesn't exist? Since the js library is generating the elements, they might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sideBarNodeRef = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

const sideBarBgColor = sideBarNodeRef ? sideBarNodeRef.style.backgroundColor:null

or

const sideBarBgColor = sideBarNodeRef ? sideBarNodeRef.getPropertyValue('background-color'):null
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 